# jquery json google ws api

Tags: jquery, json, api

hello
i am trying to get the google json from my local host
http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/v1/jsondevguide.html?#basic_query

and i getting: Line: 4984 Error: Access is denied. from the jquery
what is missing??

well this is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var _url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=fuzzy%20monkey';
        _url = 'http://code.google.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=fuzzy%20monkey';
        var _serverParam = "";

        var aa = $.getJSON(_url, _serverParam, theCallBack);
        //        alert(aa);
        //        function theCallBack(theData, theStatus) {
        //            alert(theData); alert(theStatus);
        //        }

    });
    function theCallBack(theData, theStatus) {
        alert(theData); alert(theStatus);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: which version of jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the second url seems to be broken - it returns a 404 error. However you need to add '&callback=?' to the end of the URL in order not to get a XMLHttpRequest error (Origin http://... is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

Here's the code that works:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var _url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=fuzzy%20monkey&callback=?';
    //_url = 'http://code.google.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=fuzzy%20monkey&callback=?';

    $.getJSON(_url, function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var _url = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=fuzzy%20monkey';
_url = 'http://code.google.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=fuzzy%20monkey';
```

I think you are setting _url twice, then calling 
_url = 'http://code.google.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=fuzzy%20monkey';

which fails: http://code.google.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=fuzzy%20monkey

if you set the second _url to something else and call the first established _url youl find it works.
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/images?v=1.0&q=fuzzy%20monkey - retreives a image file.

Comment: i know.. on the naivete to url its ok but... from Jquery func i get that error